# detatched linux script from cron.daily

Tags: linux, bash, background

I need to run a bash script and a perl program in detached background mode from cron.daily

I tried this last night and it hung the cron job ... I guess waiting for the programs to finish ... I tested the script from the command line and it detatches properly, but doesn't when run from cron.

cron.daily directory contains file named script1.

script1 contains:
nohup script2 &
nohup perlprogram.pl &

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any message from cron? Check /var/mail/*

Comment: If you want two independent processes, why don't you simply create two cron jobs? They can be scheduled to run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most problems with cron occur due to different environment variables. Is script2 and perlprogram.pl in your PATH when script1 is executed by cron?

Comment: that was the problem!  i didn't have full path!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At a quick guess, there may be some job control in the script preventing it from exiting without the children having terminated.

Try putting a `disown -a` after the last backgrounded job.